# Table doesn't fit parent container size on mobile

Tags: android, html, css, mobile, tabular

I'm having hard times to fit a table with 3 columns to the screen size, whatever it is.

[On this example :](http://behnam.fr/archipel/la-carte/) the table is displayed correctly on any PC screen.

However, on mobile, if you're below 480px (width), it will be displayed like this:

[image]

You can use the mobile view in Chrome Developer Tools to see the same thing ( I use "Samsung Galaxy S / S II " preset )

What can I do to make the table fit the screen ? I tried adding "width: 100%" in "style" or in the table tag (width="100%") but nothing happens.

I also tried the *meta viewport* tip, but still no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always avoid using `tables` in responsive layouts, try `dl, dt, dd` instead. Try the below sample

**HTML**

```
<section class="table_specification">
    <dl>
        <dt>Heading 1</dt>
        <dd>Description 1</dd>
   </dl>
    <dl>
        <dt>Heading 2</dt>
        <dd>Description 2</dd>
   </dl>
        <dl>
        <dt>Heading 3</dt>
        <dd>Description 3</dd>
   </dl>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
dl, dd, dt{
    margin:0;
}
.table_specification{
    display: table;
    width:100%;
    border-spacing:5px 5px;
}
.table_specification dl{    
      display:table-row;  
}
.table_specification dt, .table_specification dd{
    display: table-cell;
    width:50%;
    border:1px solid red;
}
@media only screen and (max-width:480px){
   .table_specification dd, .table_specification dt{
    display: block;
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid red;
} 
}
```

check the [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q7raanu3/4/) and resize the window to see the output

Comment: Perfect, it really fits the screen according to the size and position ( portrait / landscape ). (However, don't expect seeing columns in portrait, you'll see it more on landscape. But if you build your "table" correctly, it will be displayed quite nicely !)

Answer (score 0):

Table is not good for responsivity.If you need table, try this resolution:

[Responsive table by columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26090244/responsive-table-by-columns/26090414#26090414)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have media-queries to work with for screen sizes.

Try this on smaller sizes

1. Reduce the paddings of the cells, so you gain some space to work with
2. set a max-with to the cells so they dont get larger than you want, the text will break to the next line

Or:

Make the table cells switch from inline-block to Block on smaller screen sizes.
This way they would stack upon eachother.