# Responsive column table with headers

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a responsive column table but I would also like to include the relevant header with each column.

At the moment with the CSS:

```
@media all and (max-width:500px){
   table{
      width:100%;
   }

   td{
      display:block;
      width:100%;
   }

   tr{
      display:block;
      margin-bottom:30px;
   }
}
```

I get what it is solved on [Responsive table by columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26090244/responsive-table-by-columns)

However my full "row" of th inside my thead is still displaying as a normal row and I would like it to be split by column as well.

Is there any way I could achieve that?

Comment: You haven't defined any <TH> css.

Comment: Do you mean this? http://jsfiddle.net/sjdjrm8m/8/

Comment: Hi @AleshaOleg, I sort of mean that. My problem though is that I have a <thead> with one row representing the different column headers so ideally I would like to take the header + the full column as a whole. Does it make sense? Worse case is that I have to incorporate a new row in the body being that the header row?

Comment: @CarlosTorrecillas can you show your code?

Comment: @AleshaOleg in the example you sent every Title1, Title2, Title3, Title4, does not move with its corresponding column and the way it collapses is not what I want. I'm going to paste some of my code to show what I have

Comment: @CarlosTorrecillas ok, waiting for your code

Comment: OK, to show the example I have: http://jsfiddle.net/wckbLtm0/ I would like to have a group of Title1, r1c1, r2c1; Title2, r1c2, r1c2; Title r1c3 r2c3. However I can also see the grouping is done only by logical row. Maybe the structure I'm using is not the right one and should not be using table for this?

Comment: Looks like a possible solution could be this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26090244/responsive-table-by-columns