# How to change the floating list order horizontal to vertical

Tags: html, css

I need to change the floating list order to vertical please see my code below

```css
.pink_box{background: pink;display: inline-block;height: 110px;width: 180px;}
.pink_box ul{list-style:none;padding:0;margin:0;}
.pink_box ul li{text-align:center; color:#fff; background: none repeat scroll 0 0 black;float: left;height: 15px;margin: 0 2px 3px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pink_box">
 <ul>
     <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
        <li>8</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

I found the solution here http://jsfiddle.net/Fa722/423/

Comment: Not found solution ... :-(

my requirement is not 2 columns 


http://i.stack.imgur.com/ehpV9.png
it could be dynamic but i only need to change the float left to float down ...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Fa722/423/ i have edited .. and solved it

Answer (score 3):

there is no `float: down;`

Possible ways:

**1**. Absolute positioning
**2**. Flexbox columns

```
ul{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
```

**3**. Text columns: making the items inline-block and using CSS3 text columns

```
ul{
   column-count: 2;
   column-gap: 0;
  }

li{
   display: inline-block;
  }
```

Text columns are evenly split across the width of the container, so if you want to be very specific about those column widths you'll have to be specific about the width of the container.

A difference between this and flexbox is that it will try and split the elements across the columns equally the best it can. So you don't need to declare a height if you don't want to. Essentially it tries to make it as short as possible.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this CSS3:

```
<style>
.pink_box{background: pink;display: inline-block;height: 110px;width: 180px;}
.pink_box ul{list-style:none; padding:0;margin:0; -moz-column-count: 2; -moz-column-gap: 4px;
-webkit-column-count: 2; -webkit-column-gap: 4px;  column-count: 2; column-gap: 2px;}
.pink_box ul li{text-align:center; color:#fff; background: none repeat scroll 0 0 black;
height: 15px;margin: 0 2px 3px;
padding: 0;  width: 40px;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `column-count` property of CSS3 appropriately and add a wrapping `<div>` to the `<ul>`.

**Working Code Snippet:**

```css
.pink_box{
  background: pink;
  height: 110px;
  width: 180px; 
}

.pink_box .list_container{
  width: 81px;
}

.pink_box .list_container ul{
  list-style:none;
  padding:0;
  margin:0; 
  -webkit-column-count: 2; 
  column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-gap: 1px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-gap: 1px; /* Firefox */
  column-gap: 1px;
  height: 110px;
}
.pink_box .list_container ul li{
  text-align:center; 
  color:#fff; 
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 black;
  height: 15px;
  display: inline-block; 
  margin: 0 2px 3px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pink_box">
  <div class="list_container">
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

*Readup:*

- [column-count CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count)
- [column-gap CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-gap)

Also go over [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12332549/586051).

Comment: If you vote to close a question please don't answer it.