# CSS wrapping li items in fixed height menu

Tags: html, css

I'm a bit stumped. I'm trying to create a simple menu structure using parent/child un-ordered lists. I've run into a road block trying to figure out the css needed to achieve the menu display listed in the image below:
[image: simple ul menu structure]
Here is an example html menu structure

```html
<div class="container-div">
<ul class="level1">
  <li>Item
    <ul class="level2">
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
    </ul>  
  </li>
  <li>Item
    <ul class="level2">
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item
    <ul class="level2">
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item
    <ul class="level2">
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item
    <ul class="level2">
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item
    <ul class="level2">
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>  
</div>
```

As you can see the level 1 `<ul>` has 6 `<li>` items of varying heights depending on the contents on the level 2 `<ul>`.

For some reason, I'm completely drawing a blank on how to achieve this display effect with css. `display:inline-block;` won't work, as `<li>` numbers 5 and 6 would just display on a new line, with lots of empty space below `<li>` 2, 3, and 4.

Comment: Might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332528/how-to-display-list-items-as-columns

Comment: I think the only way to achieve this effect in pure CSS is to use CSS columns. You might need to use a JavaScript masonry library.

Comment: Thanks guys. This is exactly what I was looking for. No wonder my brain couldn't come up with the standard css :)