# How to divide radio list? Three lists from one in PHP

Tags: php, radio-button, html-table, radiobuttonlist

I have a list:

[image: IMAGE HERE - CLICK]

Here is a code:

```
$main_content .= '<div class="InnerTableContainer" >          
                     <table style="width:100%;" >
                     <tr>';
                     if(count($config['site']['newchar_vocations']$world_id]) > 1) {
                        $main_content .= '<td><table class="TableContent" width="100%" >
                                         <tr class="Odd" valign="top">
                                                <td width="160"><br /><b>Select your vocation:</b></td>
                                                <td><table class="TableContent" width="100%" >';
                         foreach($config['site']['newchar_vocations'][$world_id] as $char_vocation_key => $sample_char) {
                             $main_content .= '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="newcharvocation" value="'.$char_vocation_key.'" ';
                             if($newchar_vocation == $char_vocation_key)
                                $main_content .= 'checked="checked" ';
                                $main_content .= '>'.htmlspecialchars($vocation_name[0][$char_vocation_key]).'</td></tr>';
                         }
                        $main_content .= '</table></table></td>';
```

It's taking the names to the list from this config:

```
$config['site']['newchar_vocations'][0] = array(
  1 => 'Goku Sample',
  17 => 'Vegeta Sample',
  32 => 'Piccolo Sample',
  45 => 'C17 Sample',
  57 => 'Gohan Sample',
  71 => 'Trunks Sample',
  83 => 'Cell Sample',
  95 => 'Freeza Sample',
  111 => 'Majin Boo Sample',
  140 => 'C18 Sample',
  206 => 'Dende Sample',
  244 => 'Kuririn Sample',
  256 => 'Pan Sample',
  292 => 'Janemba Sample',
  304 => 'Tenshinhan Sample', 
  280 => 'Videl Sample', 
  316 => 'Jenk Sample', 
  192 => 'Cooler Sample', 
  328 => 'Raditz Sample', 
  340 => 'C16 Sample', 
  352 => 'Turles Sample', 
  364 => 'Bulma Sample', 
  230 => 'Bardock Sample', 
  268 => 'Kaio Sample', 
  178 => 'Chibi Trunks Sample', 
  152 => 'Uub Sample' 
);
```

How to divide this list to for example 3 parts?
For example 6 values per part? Like this:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by `parts`? Do you mean a break in the list after every six items/values?

Comment: @justbaron yes like this one: http://i.imgur.com/t6MY5Lt.png

Comment: You could do this with css, put a max height on the div and then float the radio buttons.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12332549/715105

Comment: @justbaron Can you make it for me? I do not how

Comment: @justbaron I added the CSS you provide me via link and added to my code like this:
`      $main_content .= '<ul id = "limheight"><tr><td><input type="radio" name="newcharvocation" value="'.$char_vocation_key.'" ';
      if($newchar_vocation == $char_vocation_key)
       $main_content .= 'checked="checked" ';
      $main_content .= '>'.htmlspecialchars($vocation_name[0][$char_vocation_key]).'</td></tr>';
     }
     $main_content .= '</ul></table></table></td>';`

And nothing changed

Comment: `Can you make it for me?` No mate, check out the duplicate link, or Google `divide radio list`.

Answer (score 0):

You can arrange your list with three columns only with CSS code.
You can see an example here :

```css
.col {
   -webkit-columns: 3;
   -moz-columns: 3;
   columns: 3;
}
  
p {
   margin: 0;
   background: #F0F0F0;
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <p>A....</p>
  <p>B....</p>
  <p>C....</p>
  <p>D....</p>
  <p>E....</p>
  <p>F....</p>
</div>
```

It's one of many possibilities